# Parsin JSON Using Javascript and using the result as AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, api

Hey guys, right now I'm trying to make a music discovery website just to learn more about web design and programming. It has surely been a challenge, but with help of stackoverflow I'm getting there. Anyways.....
I'm using itunes' API to return the artist albums (initially tried last.fm's API but there is way too much user submitted extras in there). iTunes only provides results in json format which I am not familiar with at all. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

When a user clicks on the artist they will see the albums for that artist. This needs to happen with ajax. I need to know how to parse items such as album name, release date and so on. here is the link to the [JSON File](http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=linkin%20park&limit=20).
Any help will be appreciated. OH and I have done some research on the net but none make any sense for what I'm planning to do.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with JavaScript objects and arrays? Because that's basically all JSON is. (Not being condescending; I was only able to make sense of XML when I learned HTML, and I only got JSON after I learned JS.)

Once you understand JS objects/arrays, if you're going to work with the JSON in PHP, you'll need to understand that JS arrays are basically the same as PHP arrays, and that JS objects are basically the same as PHP associative arrays.

The final piece is the function: When you get the JSON, it's probably just a string. If you're using PHP 5.2, you'll have access to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which converts the JSON to arrays/associative arrays.

If I'm just repeating stuff you already knew and this was no help at all, then you'll probably have to go into more detail as to what your problem is.

**EDIT**
After reading your comments on the other answer, it sounds like you're trying to do the following:

1. get the JSON into PHP, then
2. send that JSON from PHP to JavaScript, and
3. manipulate the JSON with JavaScript.

Is this correct? If it is, then almost everything I said earlier is useless. You'll probably want to start with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). All you have to do is give it the URL of the JSON, and it will return the JSON as a string.

Now, if you're just getting it with PHP so that you can send it straight to the JavaScript, then the string is all ready to go. Just `echo` it out in a way that the JS can handle:

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo $JSON ?>;
</script>
```

Note that the biggest problem with this is that it doesn't do *any* security checking at all. You'll probably be fine, but just keep that in mind.

Comment: thanks man, you have been great help.now I have a good starting place. I think I have to send the JSON using a URL string to PHP!! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sam Updated my answer. Let me know if that's any closer to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

since I'm still not absolutely clear on your use of the PHP (whether that's just how you're referring to your page generally, or if you'll be manipulating the json with the php directly), this may or may not be helpful:

Page (maybe it was generated with php?):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function search()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var resp = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
    for(var i=0;i<resp.results.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=resp.results[i].trackName+'<br/>';
    }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","it_search.php?artist="+document.getElementById('search').value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"><input type="text" id="search"/><br/>
<button type="button" onClick="search()">search</button></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Scraper:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$var=urlencode($_REQUEST["artist"]);
$file=file_get_contents("http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=".$var."&limit=20");
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I need to get JSON to php and then from PHP back to JavaScript. The page only shows how to parse when I already have the JSON.

Comment: so then it's not the parsing as much as the ajax request?

Comment: I'm just reading on some material I found and it explains how to parse JSON with javascript. Now I just don't know how to get the JSON to my PHP? Can you help?

Comment: I think you might be running up against a same origin issue (ajax as is limits where you can pull data from)...there are a few approaches, one is using a setup where you have a same domain php that scrapes the content of the second domain [do you know how to do that?] and I think that would probably work well for you here

Comment: Good idea. I have done scraping in the past so I will give it a try and once I have a satisfactory results I will post the answer. Cheers